# Convert a schedule (in wide form) to long form in R and select only some rows

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to have rows for each combination of level and and day where there is "X".

[image: wide-form schedule]

Example:

```
dat <- data.frame(1:5, matrix( c("X", "-", "X", "-", "-", "X", "X", "-", "X", "-", "X", "-", "X", "-", "X", "-", "X", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "X", "X", "-"), 5, 5, byrow=T))
colnames(dat) <- c("lvl",  "Mon",  "Tues", "Wed",  "Thur", "Fri" )
```

Comment: Please don't use EDIT: in your posts; this isn't a forum.  Every question has a detailed edit history that anyone can view.  Also, don't editorialize in your posts; that's what comments are for.  Don't put answers in your questions; that's what answers are for.  Please remain civil in your comments; rudeness is not tolerated here.

Comment: First I am asked to edit the post, than I'm scolded for editing it. Huh?

Comment: *This isn't a forum.*  Learn the conventions that exist here; don't bring your bad forum habits with you.

Comment: I am not here to argue, just I am confused about what exactly you guys want me to do? Just leave this post as it is and write next question more carefully?

Comment: The post is fine the way it is, now that the "EDIT" moniker and editorialization are gone, and the offensive comments have been removed.  The request is to make an effort to understand better how we work here, and refrain from using practices that you may have learned in other forum environments that don't work well here.  That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your schedule is stored as a matrix or data frame, you can use the `reshape2` package:

```
# generate a fake schedule
sched <- matrix(rbinom(25, 1, 1/2), 5,
  dimnames = list(1:5, c("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr")))

library(reshape2)
melt(sched)

#    Var1 Var2 value
# 1     1   Mo     0
# 2     2   Mo     0
# 3     3   Mo     1
# 4     4   Mo     0
# 5     5   Mo     1
# 6     1   Tu     0
# 7     2   Tu     1
# 8     3   Tu     1
# 9     4   Tu     0
# 10    5   Tu     1
# 11    1   We     1
# 12    2   We     1
# 13    3   We     1
# 14    4   We     0
# 15    5   We     0
# 16    1   Th     0
# 17    2   Th     1
# 18    3   Th     1
# 19    4   Th     0
# 20    5   Th     0
# 21    1   Fr     0
# 22    2   Fr     1
# 23    3   Fr     1
# 24    4   Fr     1
# 25    5   Fr     1
```

There is also the function `gather` in the package `tidyr` but it only works on data frames and it's a bit more advanced overall.

To get only the rows with `1` in the `value` column, do:

```
sched <- melt(sched)
sched[sched$value == 1, ]
```

Comment: I just had to add id.vars = c() to get the output I wanted: melt(Sche, id.vars = c( "lvl"))

Comment: @snoram there are a lot of options in the `reshape2` package. There's a nice tutorial [here](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html)